# Create dictionary<string,string> from separated string

Tags: c#, string, dictionary

My application need consume string:

```
"????infoResponse\n\\voip\\1\\g_humanplayers\\1\\g_needpass\\0\\pure\\1\\gametype\\0\\sv_maxclients\\8\\clients\\1\\mapname\\oa_rpg3dm2\\hostname\\test\\protocol\\71"
```

I'm looking for the fastest solution create `dictionary<string,string>` from this string
where first string in chain is key and next is a value.

I try

```
teststring.Split(new string[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

But don't know how convert array ToDictionary

now i have:

```
[0]: "voip"
[1]: "1"
[2]: "g_humanplayers"
[3]: "1"
[4]: "g_needpass"
[5]: "0"
[6]: "pure"
[7]: "1"
[8]: "gametype"
[9]: "0"
[10]: "sv_maxclients"
[11]: "8"
[12]: "clients"
[13]: "1"
[14]: "mapname"
[15]: "oa_rpg3dm2"
[16]: "hostname"
[17]: "test"
[18]: "protocol"
[19]: "71"
```

but i need the key and value pair:

```
 voip -> 1 
 g_humanplayers ->1
 g_needpass -> 0
```

How do I tokenize the string into key and value pairs?

Comment: Look into the `ToDictionary` LINQ method and .Split if you have several strings. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: And it would help if you could somehow say what you expect your dictionary to look like, i.e. keys and values for this example.

Comment: for example 
'g_humanplayers\\1\\g_needpass\\0'
g_humanplayers should be a key and 1 should be a value
g_needpass should be a key and 0 value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your string.

```
   string str="????infoResponse\n\\voip\\1\\g_humanplayers\\1\\g_needpass\\0\\pure\\1\\gametype\\0\\sv_maxclients\\8\\clients\\1\\mapname\\oa_rpg3dm2\\hostname\\test\\protocol\\71";
```

This will split all the value and keys in a single list

```
var list1= str.Split(new[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This will create a dictionary pair of keys and values

```
var  list2 = list1
            .Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
            .GroupBy(x => x.i / 2)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.First().s, g => g.Last().s);
```

Output

```
 var g_humanplayers = list2["g_humanplayers"].ToString();
 var g_needpass = list2["g_needpass"].ToString();
```

g_humanplayers store Value 1
g_needpass store Value 0

[image]